# django fixed fontsize in tinymce

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I have used tinymce in my django project. In my base.html I have used it as

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
tinymce.init({selector:'textarea',
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
    "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
],
theme: 'modern',
font_size: "20 px",
toolbar: "undo redo pastetext | styleselect | fontselect | fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor"
});
</script>
```

I wanto to make the fixed font size in my editor because the dafault one is too small.
From tinymce site I came to know that I should use `content_css` in order to make my fontsize fixed..

My static directory is in the root directory inside which I have made a directory named css and inside that folder I have "content_css"

Now what can I put the directory for "content_css".. Should I do like content_css:"static/css/content.css". I guess its only for django not the tinymce.. Confused in giving directory for content_css.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an easy solution assuming you are also using django-tinymce plugin?

Simply select the highcontract skin which does not include a font-size of 10px for the body. As a result the default font size of the outer (django) app applies.

```
'theme': 'advanced',
'skin': 'highcontrast',
```

Paul